# Couldn't able to download file from s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, function, download

```
downloadFileFromS3: (res, fileName) => {
    const params = { Bucket: process.env.AMZ_BUCKET, Key: fileName } // keyname can be a filename
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({ error: err })
      }
      return res.download(data)
    })
  },
```

err:Error [TypeError]: filename must be a string

Comment: How do you call your function ?